# Prime React css styles not applying in Reactjs application

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, primereact

I am working on an react js application, I had added reactbootstrap & primereact library for the styling.
the reactbootstrap library is working fine But primereact styling is not getting applied , I have followed all the steps present in getting started section, can anyone suggest me what is missing.
I am adding the Files for the refrence.
I used the below command to add files in node modules

- npm install primereact --save
- npm install primeicons --save

App.js File

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Header from './MyComponents/Header'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'primereact/resources/primereact.min.css';
import 'primeicons/primeicons.css';       
import {Todos} from './MyComponents/Todos'
import {TodoElements} from './MyComponents/TodoElements'
import {Footer} from './MyComponents/Footer'

function App() {
  
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/primereact/primereact.all.min.js"></script>
  
  return (
    <><Header title='Code With Shiva' searchBar={true}/>
    <Todos/>
    <TodoElements/>
    <Footer/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Todos.js where I am adding primereact styled button

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'primereact/button';

export const Todos = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Button label="Success" className="p-button-success" />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Adding package.json for refrence

```
{
  "name": "todos-list",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "primeicons": "^5.0.0",
    "primereact": "^7.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Adding final result image

[image]

Comment: try add 'import "primereact/resources/themes/lara-light-indigo/theme.css";'

Comment: Adding theme made it work, Thanks @foadabdollahi , BTW , one more question arises in my mind why it wasn't working without the theme

Comment: All PrimeReact components require a theme to be styled.  They don't have any naked styling.

Answer (score 6):

All PrimeReact components require a theme so just add...

```
import "primereact/resources/themes/lara-light-indigo/theme.css";
```